# My SO question was closed after only 10 views? Where does this type of question go then?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148547/strategy-for-generating-unique-and-secure-identifiers-for-use-in-a-sometimes-of) was closed after only 10 views. I guess I understand why, but after 2+ hours crafting my question (and several more researching the problem), that kinda sucks! It's not at all a stupid question and I'd love *some* sort of feedback from the broader developer community before heading off in an unprecedented direction. Is there a better home for this type of question?

Comment: Quick note here: that your question was closed does **not** mean it was stupid. The only thing it means is that it is not a good fit for SO. This is **all** it means.

Comment: You did get some feedback.  The question was closed for being "Too broad".  Just skimming over it, that seems to be entirely appropriate.  Consider trying to formulate a much more specific question that can be answered conclusively and completely in just a paragraph or two, rather than requiring something the size of a book chapter or more.

Comment: Of course while it might be more on topic on programmers, it still looks too broad for programmers.  You'll still want to narrow its scope before asking it there.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260

Comment: I've pinged a mod on programmers, I'm going to send the question there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Splitting my question in multiple smaller questions is a great suggestion. However, I'm actually more concerned with the high level question. I understand that doesn't fit the SO format very well. I was just hoping someone had a good suggestion for where this type of question _should_ go :)

Comment: I can tell that just by researching the topic and crafting the question you have solved it yourself. This is a success, not a failure.

Comment: This is not a broad question at all.  It's actually very clear and specific.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Questions containing a list of questions is always at risk of being closed as "too broad". All questions on SO are expected to have one "correct, best answer". If you have multiple questions listed that is hard. There could be one answer that answers 1,2 & 3 correctly, but is totally incorrect on 4, while another answer is spot on 4, but wrong on 1. What do you mark as correct answer then?

Some of the sub-questions (e.g. #1) are specific enough and on-topic on SO. They are welcome on SO as separate questions. Try to scale down on the background info and ask exactly the thing you need to know about each topic.

The broader "is this a good design?" is not on topic on SO. If you can implement specific parts and show code samples it might be on topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but I don't know that community's rules.

Comment: Code Review typically requires code to be included in the question.  It is not a place to discuss best practice without code.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll post it there after I have some code. But, I was really hoping to get some feedback _before_ starting to code

Comment: @herbrandson: Perhaps [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Answer (score 7):

That is too big! Try to make your question more precise. This will bring some suggestions or answers from the community.  Also be specific, and if you want, you can even split the question by creating new, smaller posts.  This stands for all sites in Stack Exchange.

**No** there is no better home for this "big" question.

Comment: While I don’t actually mind detailed questions in general, I do have to agree that just seeing the question discourages me from reading it completely… I’d suggest you to reduce it to the more important bits… :/

Comment: That makes sense. Believe it or not, I actually put a fair amount of effort into trimming it down to the size it is now ;)

Comment: @herbrandson I know your position because you took almost a great effort/time to prepare this question and when it get closed it hurts a lot.  The same rule throughout the S/W E, break into parts and it make it easy to build :) (the lesson still I'm learning).